# Aligning ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where I would compare some new and old changes within some groups (Species). I have a plot which creates the desired output, but the labels are not as desired. I would like them to be between the old and new bars. This is a bit tricky when the labels are of different length.

Example

```
library(ggplot2)
iris$change <- sample(c('new', 'old'), 150, replace = TRUE)
iris$mean1 <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length < mean(iris$Sepal.Length), 'Below', 'Above')

breaks

breaks <- unique(paste(iris$Species[iris$change == 'new'], iris$change[iris$change == 'new']))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = paste(Species, change), y = Petal.Width, fill = mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = breaks, labels = c('Setosa', 'vers', 'Virginica')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = -1.2)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(change == "new", 'new', '')), size = 3, y = 0.05) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(change == "old", 'old', '')), size = 3, y = 0.05)
```

Comment: Which labels are you talking about? The x-axis ticks? I can't tell how relevant it is to what you're trying to do, but this is one of those classic `ggplot` situations where you should probably be assigning a variable to an aesthetic, in this case `label = change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get what you want using faceting:

```
library(ggplot2)
iris$change <- sample(c('new', 'old'), 150, replace = TRUE)
iris$mean1 <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length < mean(iris$Sepal.Length), 'Below', 'Above')

ggplot(iris, aes(x = change, y = Petal.Width, fill = mean1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill') +
  facet_wrap(~Species, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white"))+
  xlab(NULL)
```